# Problems with Observer and Threads

Tags: javafx, threadpool, fxml, observer-pattern

I am new to Java and JavaFX I have got a really big problem with my code. I work with JavaFX and Scene Builder.

My goal is it to calculate the heat equation of a room, and now I am trying to display my result on a label.

I calculate the equation in a loop and the label should update everytime to show the last result.  I found a video on youtube and I tried to do it like this but it does not work. =( maybe you could help me :-/

This is not the complete code, I deleted unnecessary stuff.

I get no errors, but it doesn't work.

[youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2aB9n472U0)

This is my first class where I calculate the heat:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Raum {
    int zeit;
    int startTemperatur;

    // length, width, height
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    double sensorwert;
    String sensorwertString;
    private final List<TemperaturSensorListener> listeners = new ArrayList();
    //and so on

    public Raum() {    
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        service.submit(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            temperaturverlauf(); // is this correct?
            for (TemperaturSensorListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.onReadingChanged();
            }
        });    
    }

    // Calculate Heat equation
    public void temperaturverlauf() {
        double[][][] raumTemp = new double[x][y][z];
        double[][][] raumTempneu = new double[x][y][z];
        zeit = 0;

        //Start temperature for every position
        for (int posX = 0; posX < x; posX++) {
            for (int posY = 0; posY < y; posY++) {
                for (int posZ = 0; posZ < z; posZ++) {
                    raumTemp[posX][posY][posZ] = startTemperatur;    
                }
            }
        }

        /*Heater*/
        raumTemp[0][0][0] = startHeizung;

        while (zeit < 100) {
            for (int posX = 0; posX < x; posX++) {
                for (int posY = 0; posY < y; posY++) {
                    for (int posZ = 0; posZ < z; posZ++) {
                        // Compute the heat of every quadrant in the room
                        // upper left corner
                        if (posX == 0 && posY == Array.getLength(raumTemp[0]) - 1 && posZ == 0) {
                            raumTempneu[posX][posY][posZ] = raumTemp[posX][posY][posZ] - temperaturleitfähigkeit * (4 * raumTemp[posX][posY][posZ] - raumTemp[posX + 1][posY][posZ] - raumTemp[posX][posY - 1][posZ] - raumTemp[posX][posY][posZ + 1] - mauertemp);
                        }    
                        // Upper right corner , walls and so on
                    }    
                }
            }

            raumTemp = raumTempneu;

            // print out the heat of the sensor position and convert it to a string. this String has to be displayed in a label
            System.out.println("raum1:" + raumTemp[Array.getLength(raumTemp) - 1][Array.getLength(raumTemp[0]) - 1][1]);
            sensorwert = raumTemp[Array.getLength(raumTemp) - 1][Array.getLength(raumTemp[0]) - 1][1];
            sensorwertString = Double.toString(sensorwert);
        }
    }

    public void addListener(TemperaturSensorListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public String getSensorwertString() {
        return sensorwertString;
    }
}
```

This is my second class with the label in it:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    private Raum r = new Raum();

    // Slider for heater temperature
    @FXML
    private Slider slider1;

    // Label with the String from the other class
    @FXML
    private final Label anzeigetempaktuell1 = new Label(r.getSensorwertString());

    // Textfields so user can type in the size of the room
    @FXML
    private TextField laenge;

    @FXML
    private TextField breite;

    @FXML
    private TextField hoehe;

    // starttemperature
    @FXML
    private TextField tempAktuell;

    // target temperature
    @FXML
    private TextField tempGewuenscht;

    //this button should start the application after the user typed in the required values
    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        r.temperaturverlauf();// i think this is wrong
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        slider1.setMin(17);
        slider1.setMax(85);
        slider1.setValue(45);

        slider1.valueProperty().addListener((ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
            r.maxHeizung = (double) new_val;
            System.out.println(r.maxHeizung);
        });

        // this is a relevant part i think but i think its the same like in the video
        r.addListener(new TemperaturSensorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReadingChanged() {
                updateTemperatureLabel();
            }

            private void updateTemperatureLabel() {
                Platform.runLater(() -> anzeigetempaktuell1.setText(r.getSensorwertString()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the last class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SmartHome extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I work with this `FXMLDocumentController` class and the guy in the video didn't.  I don't know if it was correct to write everything into the `initialize` method.  I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your code? It's very difficult to read as it is.

Comment: i tried :-o  I hope it is better now. Thank you

Comment: For some reason, the amount of whitespace in the pasted code was [driving me crazy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsoOG6ZeyUI), so I removed some of it and fixed the some punctuation.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Doesn't your `while (zeit < 100)` loop just run indefinitely?

Comment: oh I deleted it accidentally when I edited my code for this post.

Comment: hm what more can I say..Do you see the sleep in the constructor in my first class? i cant see that sleep in my output so it seems that this code is not executed :-/ my label doesnt change at all. i think there has to be another command in the handleButtonAction in my second class ? could it be ? or something is missing in the start method ? or maybe its wrong that call temperaturverlauf(); in the constructor of the first class? i dont know =(

Comment: Deleted *what* accidentally? I don't see any reason the loop would exit in your first version either. And what does "I can't see that sleep in my output" mean? What do you expect to see?

Comment: i deleted zeit++. but only here not in my code.

 that means that i expect that the output comes in an interval of one second and not all 100 in 5 seconds. :-o

Answer (score 0):

Your `sleep` call is outside the call to `temperaturverlauf`. The task you send to the executor sleeps once for 1000ms then runs through all of your computations, dumping the output to `System.out`. Then, at the end, it calls your observer.

It sounds like that's not what you want. If you want a pause in the middle of your computation, then that's where you need to put the `sleep` call. Similarly, if you want the observers notified each time the values change, then at the value change is where you need to call `onReadingChanged`.

I recommend an architectural revision to make this redesign easier: write your computation method so that it computes exactly one change. This will make it easier to separate your concerns, so that another agent can follow this sequence:

1. Call the method to compute one temperature change.
2. Update the label with the new value.
3. Sleep for one second.